# JBoos EAP 7.1.4 local Datasource lookup

Tags: java, jboss, datasource, jboss7.x, jndi

I am facing issue on looking up a local (oracle) data source configured in JBOSS EAP 7.1.4 version.

The Data source is configured properly and I am able to test the connection successfully from the console. However I am not able to lookup/get the connection using the datsource

Standalone.xml entries

```xml
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/jdbc/TEST_DS" pool-name="TEST_DS" use-java-context="false">
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@//XXX.XX.XX.XX:1521/DES</connection-url>
    <driver>OracleDriver</driver>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>80</max-pool-size>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>User</user-name>
        <password>pass</password>
    </security>
</datasource>
<drivers>
    <driver name="OracleDriver" module="com.oracle.jdbc">
        <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
    </driver>
</drivers>

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
    <bindings>
        <lookup name="java:/jdbc/TEST_DS" lookup="java:jboss/jdbc/TEST_DS"/>
    </bindings>
    <remote-naming/>
</subsystem>
```

```java
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");
env.put("jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT", "false");
env.put("remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS", "false");
env.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
env.put("remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_DISALLOWED_MECHANISMS","JBOSS-LOCAL-USER");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote+http://localhost:8080");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "admin");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "admin");

InitialContextic = new InitialContext(env);
DataSource ds = (DataSource) ic.lookup("TEST_DS");
Connection con = ds.getConnection();
```

I am getting javax.naming.NameNotFoundException
I have tried options with 
"/env/jdbc/TEST_DS"
"jdbc/TEST_DS"
"/jdbc/TEST_DS"
"jdbc/TEST_DS"
"java:jboss/jdbc/TEST_DS"

I am new to Jboss.. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try not use 'urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0' config,just                                           <datasource jndi-name="java:/jdbc/TEST_DS" ...                                                        
 and                                                                                                                       DataSource ds = (DataSource) ic.lookup("jdbc/TEST_DS") should work